# How to make hidden fields for model automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I am looking for way to create hidden fields in view automatically. 
Here is my model:

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;
    public ComlexType MyComplexType{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

In view I have to enumerate all model fields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id);
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.MyComplexType.Title);

...
```

Comment: You can try to add a class hidden to your css. And remove and add this class in javascript. Or did I interpreted your question wrongly?

Comment: Wrong I am asking a way to enumerate all fields with html helper. Here should be something with reflection and recursion..

Comment: @Yara, once you know it is something with reflection and recursion, what effort have you put in up til now?

Answer (score 1):

If you have many types you want to do this for, a helper and reflection are probably best.

If you have a small number of these, it may be easier to create a partial that adds exactly what hiddens you want

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("HiddenComplexType", Model );}
```

You need to pass the model, not the ComplexType member.  You'll probably want an interface or base class the partial can use as the model

```
interface IHasComplexType
{
    ComplexType  GetComplexType();
}

public class MyViewModel : IHasComplexModel
{
    public ComplexType GetComplexType() { return MyComplexType;}
}
```

There are other ways to do it but you get into reflection and a helper is probably just as easy.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can use:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

In your model you can add the HiddenInput attribute:

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;
    public ComlexType MyComplexType{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the next solution:
The 'ReflectionHelper' class reflect model properties, and in 'properties' variable are model fields {{'Id',1},{'Name','Myname'}, etc}:

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static void IterateProps(Object obj, string baseProperty, ref Dictionary<string,object> properties )
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var baseType = obj.GetType();
            var props = baseType.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in props)
            {
                var name = property.Name;
                var propType = property.PropertyType;
                if (propType.IsClass && propType.Name != "String")
                {
                    IterateProps(property.GetValue(obj, null), baseProperty + "." + property.Name, ref properties);
                }
                else
                {
                    properties.Add(baseProperty + "." + name, property.GetValue(obj, null));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in view I do the next:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyStep1", "Wizard"))
{
    var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    ReflectionHelper.IterateProps(Model, Model.GetType().Name,ref properties);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="@property.Key" value="@property.Value"/>
    }
}
```

It is a part of wizard solution, later I am going to write article about wizard on MVC, maybe someone will found useful.