# ModelState is not valid when i pass input through reflection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, html, razor, system.reflection, ef-database-first

Im working on a big form on multiple view. Since i use `db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified` i need to pass all field to the request through hidden fields. I have 30+ fields. I needed a clean way to generate all hidden fields (since they going to be used in all view).

I found a post on using reflection : [How to make hidden fields for model automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309204/how-to-make-hidden-fields-for-model-automatically/11310851)

It seemed to worked well for some times, but as i added new fields in my database (db first), i needed to manually add the hidden field in my form because my ModelState would never be valid even if the hidden fields exist. I want to know if i'm doing something wrong, or if i just use an other approach.

Here is my Reflection method

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static void IterateProps(Object obj, string baseProperty, ref Dictionary<string, object> properties)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var baseType = obj.GetType();
            var props = baseType.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in props)
            {

                var name = property.Name;
                var propType = property.PropertyType;
                if (propType.Name != "ICollection`1" && (propType.Name == "String" || propType.Name == "Int32" || propType.Name == "Boolean"))
                {
                    if (propType.IsClass && propType.Name != "String")
                    {
                        IterateProps(property.GetValue(obj, null), property.Name, ref properties);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        properties.Add(name, property.GetValue(obj, null)??"");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how it is used in my form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    //Form fields...

    var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    ReflectionHelper.IterateProps(Model, Model.GetType().Name, ref properties);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="@property.Key" name="@property.Key" value="@property.Value" />
    }
    // Here is a case i needed to add fields.
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RapportIncident.FirstOrDefault().FK_Blessure); //int
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateCreation) // datetime

    <input type="submit" value="Suivant" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: 
    #eeeeee;border-color: blue;" />
}
```

Comment: Not the answer you want to hear but: You create a new model with only the fields you want exposed to the user. Then you only need to validate the absolutely minimum amount of fields. When you save to the database, you will map those properties to the entity model committed to the database. Also remember the hidden fields can be examined by the user so you'd need to be aware of sensitive data you would leak this way.

Comment: Like a view model for each of my form steps?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @Jasen When the view model is returned, he would have to assign each value retrieved to the database line one by one like so:
`CurrentEntity.Var1 = model.Var1;`
`CurrentEntity.Var2 = model.Var2;`
`CurrentEntity.Var99 = model.Var99;`
`db.SaveChanges();`
This is almost as long as putting all hidden fields in the view

Comment: But it is more secure as you're not exposing hidden fields which can be seen and tampered with. There are tools such as AutoMapper https://automapper.org/ which can ease the pain.